# How to write RSpec for a controller method not accessible via GET and uses params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

```
def method1
   if params[:hotel].present?
   end
end

def method2 //accessed via GET
    @hotel = params[:hotel]
    method1
end
```

So, now I want to write a RSpec test for `method1`. How do I preset the `params` variable? Just to be clear, I cannot write

```
get :'method1', request_params
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If it is not accessible, it should be private. If it should be private, you shouldn't be testing it.

Comment: I totally understand that. But, I am only trying to test the behavior of the function because it is critical. Surely, there has to be a way. I know it may not make sense to test private functions, but, from a programming point of view, is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by literally setting the params yourself and calling the method on the controller eg:

```
expect(@controller).to receive(:params).and_return(:hotel => "Sample Hotel")
expect(...) # your spec expectations here
expect(@controller.send(:method1)).to eq(expected_return_value)
```

As mentioned, though, it is considered not best practice to test private/non-action methods of your controller...

Instead you're expected to test the public actions, and test that your private methods are doing the right thing by passing in all the possible variations and getting the final results - eg instead of specifically testing method1, you'd instead test method2 with all the variants that method1 should expect to respond to correctly.

Comment: In my test code,

`params = {}
params[:hotel]  = "Sample Hotel"
@controller.send(:method1)`

On running the test case and putting `binding.pry` inside `method1`, I find `params` to still be empty.

Comment: ok, went and dug out how I did it... Actually i set an expectation on the controller. `params` is just another method, after all. I've updated my answer to reflect.